# Keychain asks permission for multiple accounts

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

In my MacOS app I am storing email accounts data, so 5 application passwords are saved in Keychain. When the app starts, Keychain asks 5 times to Always allow... Is there a way to ask Keychain to accept my app once? Adium for example, stores multiple accounts data, and in their Keychain there is only one entry (of kind: "Internet password").

Is code-signing the only way to avoid this?

**Store:**

```
+(void)storePasswordKeychainWithPassAndKey:(NSString *)passwordStr:(NSString *)accountNameStr {
const char * accountName = [accountNameStr UTF8String];
const char * password = [passwordStr UTF8String];

OSStatus status;
status = SecKeychainAddGenericPassword(NULL, 
                                      strlen(serviceName), serviceName,
                                      strlen(accountName), accountName,
                                      strlen(password), password, 
                                      NULL);
```

}

**Get**

```
+(NSString *) getPasswordKeychainWithKey: (NSString *)accountNameStr {
    const char * accountName = [accountNameStr UTF8String];
    void *password = nil;
    UInt32 passwordLen = 0;
    SecKeychainItemRef itemRef = nil;

    OSStatus status1;
    status1 = SecKeychainFindGenericPassword(NULL, 
                                             strlen(serviceName), serviceName,
                                             strlen(accountName), accountName,
                                             &passwordLen, &password,
                                             &itemRef);

    if (status1 == noErr) {
        NSData* passwordData = [NSData dataWithBytes:password length:passwordLen];
        SecKeychainItemFreeContent (NULL, password);
        return [NSString stringWithCString:[passwordData bytes] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Would you post the code that you're using to store the items in Keychain?